Why am I receiving a 'ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration' warning for my Flutter app for iOS?
In my penultimate submission to the App Store for iOS, I received an email telling me that there is a missing API declaration. This was what it said:
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

I came across other posts on the site that explained I need to create a 'PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy' file with the right declarations, to fix this.
Therefore, to try and rectify this, I created my PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file with that I thought was the correct information, to avoid this warning again. This is what I created:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>DDA9.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict/>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

I placed this file in my Flutter app's directory in Android Studio like so:
appname > iOS > PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
Again, this was as a result of the instructions I saw in other posts, including here. However, I uploaded a new version today with a tweak, yet I received the same missing API declaration email. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I was expecting this would be sufficient to avoid the error in the future but as it happened again, I can't have done it right.
Thanks for the help!

You need to open your project in Xcode and make sure that you have added the privacyinfo file to your target, otherwise it will not be included in the built application

Hey @Paulw11 thanks so much for the rapid response. I've opened it Xcode but at the risk of sounding rather stupid, how do I ensure it is added to my target?

Click on the file in the navigator on the left and then in the inspector on the far right, make sure it is added to your target (probably called Runner).  If the file doesn't appear in the navigator on the left, then just drag it in from Finder - Xcode will prompt you to add it to a target

Thanks mate. I'll give that a go and see where I get. :)
